# Upgrading Xcode to 3.2.6

Tags: xcode

Hey I am upgrading to Xcode 3.2.6 now to test my app on 4.3 device as I will apply for the developer license tomorrow. Does the Xcode install itself over the old one or should I be worried about something?

Answer (score 3):

You have nothing to worry about if you mean *upgrade* (not downgrade).

Answer (score 1):

Xcode installs over itself, unless you choose a different install directory. Theres nothing to worry about, you can always do a complete uninstall and re-install a previous version *(If you have it saved somewhere, I have the SDK's saved since iPhone SDK 3.0)*